# Ldap group configuration in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ldap

I recently installed Jenkins and Ldap plugin. I am able to setup User Authentication in Jenkins but now I want to setup groups as well. However, my organization's Ldap is bit tricky and I am not been able to set it up properly from group perspective. Here is my company's LDAP tree structure:

[image: LDAP Tree Structure]

I am using Java 1.8, Jenkins LDAP Plugin 1.20, Jenkins 2.176.2

Here is what I am trying in LDAP fields:
[image: LDAP Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this configuration :

```
root DN             : dc=domain,dc=com       # root base dn
User search base    : ou=People              # relative to the root search base
Group search base   : ou=Groups              # relative to the root search base
User search filter  : uid={0}
Group search filter : (& (cn={0}) (| (objectclass=groupOfNames) (objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames) (objectclass=posixGroup)))
Group membership    : (| (member={0}) (uniqueMember={0}) (memberUid={1}))
```

- The [Group search filter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin#LDAPPlugin-Groupsearchfilter) above is the default value, use it as is if you're not sure which objectClass defines your groups, otherwise remove the OR conditions to reduce the scope of the search, eg. : `(& (cn={0})(objectclass=groupOfNames))`. The most common objet class used to manage groups is `groupOfNames` that provides the `member` attribute to handle memberships.
- The [Group membership](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin#LDAPPlugin-Groupmembership) above is set to default as well (in mode *"Search for groups containing user"*). Now, if your groups have objectClass "groupOfNames" for example, you just need the filter `member={0}`. Another objectClass might rely on another membership attribute (like "uniqueMember" for "groupOfUniqueNames"). That said, if your backend provides the `memberOf` attribute, you would probably prefer switching to the other mode *"Parse user attribute for list of groups"* and set `Group membership attribute : memberOf` (see [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin#LDAPPlugin-Parseuserattributeforlistofgroups)).

Comment: Thanks Eric. I tried above settings. However, it didn't fix the issue. I am getting this error:
***No LDAP group membership reported.
If the user is a member of some LDAP groups then the group membership settings are probably configured incorrectly. ***

My User is part of several LDAP Groups which are public and any authenticated user is able to see them.

Comment: Ok. I solved it by tweaking your solution just a little bit.
in Jenkins field, "Search for LDAP groups containing user 
  Group membership filter" is used this: (| (member={0}) (uniqueMember={0}) (eduid={1})).

Comment: Ok, I'd never have thought about 'eduid' attribute (not commonly used) thank you for the feedback !