# Is It Possible To Search Two OU's In Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, ldap

In Jenkins, there is a configureSecurity section that defines the connection to AD with the LDAP Plugin. The product that uses this Jenkins has been sold to another company, but users from both companies need to still have access to the Jenkins instance in the short term.

Original LDAP Settings

- User Search Base: cn=Users,DC=company,DC=com
- User Search Filter:   uid={0}
- Group Search Base: OU=Groups
- Group Search Filter: (&(cn={0})(objectclass=group)

New LDAP Settings

- User Search Base: OU=NewCompany
- User Search Filter: uid={0}
- Group Search Base: OU=Groups
- Group Search Filter: (& (cn={0})(objectclass=group)

With the new LDAP Settings, all users in OU=NewCompany can log into Jenkins, but all Users from the previous company cannot. Is there a way to allow Users from both to log in?

[image]

**Here are the things i've tried (any field not specified stayed the same as above):**

- Group search filter: (|(cn={0})(memberOf=OU=NewCompany,DC=company,DC=com)(objectclass=group))

*result*: NewCompany users can log in, but old company cannot

- User search base: OU=NewCompany,cn=User,DC=company,DC=com
- Group search filter: (|(cn={0})(memberOf=OU=NewCompany,DC=company,DC=com)(objectclass=group))

*result*: both sets of users could not log in

research stackoverflow and the closest post to an answer was:
[Ldap group configuration in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117873/ldap-group-configuration-in-jenkins)

Comment: Do the users of both companies log into the same AD domain? You could leave the 'User search base' blank to allow every user on the domain to login.